# Pulling a URI XML location through Flash Vars in CS3

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

I'm currently doing a project that has to be multi-lingual. I need to be able to use Flash Var's to locate the XML file.

Any ideas why the below code does not work?

Here is my AS3 code:

```
var xmlPath:String;
xmlPath = root.loaderInfo.parameters(encodeURIComponent["xmlPath"]);
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="195" height="160">
<param name="movie" value="../../../desktop.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="xmlPath=привет/mp3.xml" />
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. -->
<param name="expressinstall" value="../../../expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../../../desktop.swf" width="195" height="160">
<!--<![endif]-->
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="xmlPath=привет/mp3.xml" />
<param name="expressinstall" value="../../../expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
<div>
  <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the flash vars because of the slashes.

[EDIT]

```
//Javascript
<param name="FlashVars" value="xmlPath=привет&#47;mp3.xml" />

// AS3
var xmlPath:String;
xmlPath = unescape( root.loaderInfo.parameters(encodeURIComponent["xmlPath"]) );
```

If this doesn't work verify that the mp3.xml exists in the browser.

```
 http://yourserver.com/привет/mp3.xml
```

Comment: var xmlPath:String;
xmlPath = root.loaderInfo.parameters(escape["xmlPath"]);

This does still not work.

Comment: you escape it in the javascript side and unescape it in the AS3 side.